# Running proguard on application code messes up unit tests

Tags: java, maven, obfuscation, proguard

Im trying to obfuscate code in main (see project structure below) with the proguard-maven-plugin. The obfuscation seems to work just fine but when I reach the test phase I get compile errors since the test classes was never a part of the obfuscation.

main/java/com.foo.bar.HelloWorld.java

test/java/com.foo.bar.HelloWorldTest.java

My maven pom is configured like:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>process-classes-with-proguard</id>
                    <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <proguardVersion>4.8</proguardVersion>
                        <maxMemory>256m</maxMemory>
                        <injar>classes</injar>
                        <libs>
                            <lib>${java.home}/../Classes/classes.jar</lib>
                        </libs>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                        <options>
                            <option>@proguard.cfg</option>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is that I have to point to a jar or a folder on which proguard will run. In this case, I point to my classes folder. The problem is that I have the test classes in a different folder: test-classes. So,  HelloWorld.java will become A.java and the test code is unaware of this and can't compile.

How should I approach this problem? I guess I still want my test classes in a separate folder. And I don't wanna configure proguard to keep all files that are being used in the tests since there are code I wanna obfuscate AND test.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could add the test folder as well, or include the common parent folder instead. But this doesn't help as the ProGuard optimizer seems to cause problems further down: you'll get "class xx has no public constructor TestCase()". For the moment I'm stuck here as well.